disable Alt shortcut in Lyx
I am new with Lyx,and I am using key mapping on my machine (for example Alt+L replaces right arrow). However, when using it in Lyx, it focus on toolbar on Alt press, and therefore it doesn't work as expected (for example Alt+L moves right in toolbar tabs).
Tried to disable this shortcut on  preferences, but it doesnt show there.
Noting there is a similar Alt behavior on Notepad and Word, but it doesn't conflict with the key mapping there.
I'd be glad to get any idea how to solve it

Tools > Preferences > Editing > Shorcuts

@Fran the Alt shortcut doesnt show there, only with another keys.

There are dozens of shortcuts with Alt in that place  (at least in the default configuration of a Linux) and you can set many more as you want. The question is if there is a configurable function for what you are trying to do. For instance, I can change the char-left function from "Left" (← key)  to Alt+L and use this shortcut to move the cursor to the left in the text one character, however, this is not useful for the menu navigations (no idea if there are another function for this).

@Fran You are right , but i meant for the specific shortcut using alt itself without any other key, which leads to focus on the menu navigations. My question is if there is any way to remove / replace the shortcut with another key
